# Resources in apk files coming from jars

Tags: android

I have noticed that some jar's resources (such as META-INF/**) are not included in apk files but that some others (xml, dtd, xsd) are kept (I'm using Android Studio 0.2).

Does anybody have a comprehensive list of what kind of resources are excluded from jars when added as libraries in an Android project?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of experiment, it seems that all files are kept (txt, no extensions, etc.) except those in the META-INF folder...